# Backbone collection is not updating when api is polled

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I'm having some trouble getting change events to fire when a model is updated via polling of an endpoint. I'm pretty sure this is because the collection is not actually updated. I'm using the [new option](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) (`update: true`) in Backbone 0.9.9 that tries to intelligently update a collection rather than resetting it completely.

When I insert a `console.log(this)` at the end of the `updateClientCollection` function, it appears that `this.clientCollection` is not updating when `updateClientCollection` is called via `setInterval`. However, I do see that the endpoint is being polled and the endpoint is returning new and different values for clients.

```
managementApp.ClientListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'management-client-list',
  template: _.template( $('#client-list-template').text() ),

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll( this );
    this.jobId = this.options.jobId
    //the view owns the client collection because there are many client lists on a page
    this.clientCollection = new GH.Models.ClientStatusCollection();
    this.clientCollection.on( 'reset', this.addAllClients );
    //using the initial reset event to trigger this view's rendering
    this.clientCollection.fetch({
      data: {'job': this.jobId}
    });
    //start polling client status endpoint every 60s
    this.intervalId = setInterval( this.updateClientCollection.bind(this), 60000 );
  },

  updateClientCollection: function() {
    //don't want to fire a reset as we don't need new view, just to rerender
    //with updated info
    this.clientCollection.fetch({
      data: {'job': this.jobId},
      update: true,
      reset: false
    });
  },

  render: function() {
      this.$el.html( this.template() );
      return this;
  },

  addOneClient: function( client ) {
    var view = new managementApp.ClientView({model: client});
    this.$el.find( 'ul.client-list' ).append( view.render().el );
  },

  addAllClients: function() {
    if (this.clientCollection.length === 0) {
      this.$el.find( 'ul.client-list' ).append( 'No clients registered' );
      return;
    } 
    this.$el.find( 'ul.client-list' ).empty();
    this.clientCollection.each( this.addOneClient, this );
  }
});

managementApp.ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  className: 'management-client-item',
  template: _.template( $('#client-item-template').text() ),

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll( this );
    this.model.on( 'change', this.render );
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your code, you're only binding on the `reset` event of the collection.

According to the docs, `Backbone.Collection` uses the `.update()` method after fetching when you pass `{ update: true }` as part of your fetch options.

[`Backbone.Collection.update()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-update) fires relevant `add`, `change` and `remove` events for each model. You'll need to bind to these as well and perform the relevant functions to update your UI.

In your case, you could bind to your existing `addOneClient` method to the `add` event on your collection.

In your `ClientView` class, you can bind to the `change` and `remove` events to re-render and remove the view respectively. Remember to use [`listenTo()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) so the `ClientView` object can easily clean-up the events when it `remove()`'s itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually do bind those events in the ClientView, but I tried to omit as much code as possible while still providing a test case, sorry if this was confusing.

In any case, I don't think the change event is firing because clientCollection which is owned by ClientListView is not being updated, even when I change the models server side, and watch the response from the endpoint in the "Network" tab of the Chrome's Dev tools. I wonder if I'm changing the context (or something else) of the collection when I try to update it using setInterval.

Comment: Sorry, I missed binding in the view... so you've got models changing but the `change` event isn't being fired?

Comment: That's what's odd. The models are not being updated even when the api is return different values.

Comment: How are you checking the models aren't even being updated? I'm guessing you've probably got it working by now?